# Why does Loki take the Tesseract?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, thor-ragnarok, avengers-infinity-war, loki

In *Thor: Ragnarok*, while looking for the Eternal Flame in Odin's vault, Loki comes upon the Tesseract and steals it off screen. In *Avengers: Infinity War*,

> Loki pretends to offer the Tesseract, which contains an Infinity Stone, to Thanos in an effort to distract him and give the Hulk enough time to attack him. The attack fails, and Loki pretends to lend his services to Thanos, only to betray him *again*, leading to his death.

Given these events, why would Loki steal the Tesseract if he wasn't planning on giving to Thanos?

Comment: ... do you have some reason to think that Loki *anticipated* the attack on their ship?  If not, I would assume he just stole it for himself.

Comment: He is *God of Mischief*. What else can you expect from him?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Why not?

Loki did, after all, steal the Tesseract once before (back in *The Avengers*) in order to obtain an army and transport it to Earth. While that was indirectly at the behest of Thanos, it shows that the Tesseract is a particularly powerful, valuable, and useful item.

It’s thus not hugely surprising that when we see Loki wander past it unattended in the Asgardian treasure room, while searching for an artefact that he intends to use to destroy Asgard itself, he thinks “You know what? I might just pop that in my pocket real quick.”

Comment: minor quibble: Loki was attempting to retrieve the Tesseract for 'The Other' *in exchange* for an army to subjugate Earth. The Other was working at the behest of Thanos.

Comment: @NKCampbell: ah! Yes, good point.